# ActiveRecord autogenerating Schema.rb file with force::cascade that deletes my records

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I am creating a Sinatra app with ActiveRecord to persist data. When I run rake db:migrate it auto-generates a schema.rb file that contains the table name with force::cascade. This will not let me save/persist my data. If i delete this file I CAN save/persist the data. However every migration makes this schema file. I do not know how to stop this from happening.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t| 
      t.string :name 
      t.string :email 
      t.string :password_digest 
  end
end 
end
```

```
require "./config/environment"
require "./app/models/user"
class UserC < Sinatra::Base

  configure do
    set :views, "app/views"
    enable :sessions
    set :session_secret, "password_security"
  end

end
```

```
require "bundler" 
Bundler.require

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "sqlite3",
  :database => "development.sqlite"
)

require_all 'app'
require_all 'db'
```

```
require_relative './config/environment'

use Rack::MethodOverride
#use Rack::Session::Cookie
run UserController
```

```
#gemfile # frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }

# gem "rails"
gem 'activerecord', :require => 'active_record'

gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-nav'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'rake'
gem 'require_all'
gem 'rack_session_access'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', :require => 'sinatra/activerecord'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'thin'
gem 'tux'
```

Comment: "_This will not let me save/persist my data_" How did you come to this conclusion? `schema.rb` is merely a representation of the database schema at the time it was created or last migrated, and is generated by reading the schema from the database. The existence of this file has no impact on your ability to write to your database. If you have a specific error that you've received then post that error and exact steps to reproduce it.

Comment: Binding.pry. it creates the record(i.e. User.all.count == 1). Then upon redirect it deleted the record (I.e. force: : delete in the repl  and User.all.count ==0).

Comment: Sooo. If I delete this file it saves/persists the record. When I run a migration I get the file back and force::Cascade in the repl (pry) with the record being deleted upon redirect.

Comment: None of what you have said in comments makes much sense. The existence of schema.rb will not cause records not to persist. Additionally, these are not steps to reproduce. If you have a specific error or unexpected result then you must post in your question the **exact** steps to reproduce it. You don't even have any `User.create` or `User.new.save` code in your example!

Comment: deletion of schema.rb my program will persist. another migration I get the force::Cascade. The record will not persist. I use a form to create a new user, post uses User.create(params). Then redirect location the record vis no longer there. So when it exists User.all will have it. Then in the redirect User.all is empty. It redirect another action controller 'user/:id'. If I delete the file then it will get literally user/1 and everything works like it should. When I delete the schema then you see the :force:Cascade in the relp and the record is then gone in the redirect.

Comment: I have asked you twice to place in your question the **exact** steps and the **exact** code necessary to reproduce this error. The comments you have left are not helpful. Additionally, you are insisting that the problem is the existence of schema.rb and I am telling you that is **not the issue**. That is **not** how schema.rb works or why it exists. I have voted to close this question as off-topic because it does not include the code necessary to reproduce the issue. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I am leaving this for future users who have confusing errors when building a custom Sinatra ActiveRecord app.

The lesson learned is to know exactly what all your gems are doing. In my question the error was coming from the environment file. require_all "db" was added because I assumed require_all gave my app access to the files specified. require_all literally will run that file. It's important to note that this environment file is run for every request made to the db. Thus the db folder which contains the file for create_table was run for each get request made. Upon deleting require_all 'db' my app started working perfectly.